# SharePoint Document Set Version Extension

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-server, document-set, version-history

**Before reading further, please note this is not a simple 'how do I enable versioning' and, as far as I can tell, nothing similar has been asked before...**

Instead I am looking for any solutions (3rd party or OOTB) or novel suggestions for an extension to document set versions so that users are presented with a friendlier user interface than the default version history dialogue that we all know and love.

This is a very specific request from a senior stakeholder at my company who requires the highlighting/comparison of document set versions in which we are already displaying a custom ASPX page of properties and lookups against other data in the site. The user has previously used (and most likely prefers) the Atlassian Confluence offering (https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) which provides such functionality.

So far I have explored the following no code solutions:

- Allowing users to track their own changes through Word and then uploading the document to the correct document set. This is not an option due to the number of clicks users have to navigate through and the loss of centralised tracking etc. through the doc set properties
- Providing users with the ability to mark their changes in the document set with rich text highlighting (has to be enabled through SPD for document sets) which was initially promising but places the reliance on users to remember to highlight changes correctly.

I have also noticed a frustrating feature with version control which, in the history dialogue box, properties with a large number of characters (we have extended most fields to be greater than 250 - I know this is probably not recommended but needed to be done) are clipped so that the entire field is not visible. Through PowerShell I can see that the values are fully stored in the Snapshot Collection for each document set.

Currently, I am working on the assumption that this is the only way to access version history and a custom server side solution (CSOM doesn't seem to expose these properties) will be the only option going forward. Ideally a no-code option (especially not server side) would be preferable so reaching out to you wonderful experts for some insights.

Really appreciate any responses...

Comment: Wondering if anyone had some thoughts on this before I dive into a custom solution for the customer?